# Border is working in Google Chrome but isn't working in IE

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, gridview

I've made a GridView with asp.net and it has the bordercolor:black.
Then I made the lines that I don't want to see white. I'm also working with child, maybe this isn't working in IE.
This is my styling, which I wrote directly inside the aspx file:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .GridView2 tbody tr th {
       border-top: thin solid white;
       border-left:thin solid white; 
       padding:5px;
       text-align:center;
   } 
       .GridView2 tbody tr td {
       border-top: thin solid white;
       border-left:thin solid white;
   }

    .GridView2 tbody tr:last-child td{
        border-bottom:thin solid white;
    }
    .GridView2 tbody tr th:last-child,.GridView2 tbody td:last-child{
        border-right:thin solid white;
    }
    .GridView2 tbody tr td{
       padding:5px;

    }

</style>
```

And then this is my asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="25" DataSourceID="DataSource_struktur" 
    AllowSorting="True" ForeColor="#666666" CellSpacing="1" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,###,###}" 
    CaptionAlign="Left"  Width="400px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="GridView2"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly=true HeaderText="Master Accounts" DataFormatString="{0:#,0} CMA" DataField="cma" SortExpression="cma" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly=true DataField="sa_cnt" HeaderText="Service Accounts" SortExpression="sa_cnt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
        <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
   </Columns>

    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="#666666" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#11AAFF" Font-Names='"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Sans' 
        Font-Size="12px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
```

I'm sorry I can't post a picture of both tables, because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None"` in your grid view control. Please remove this property then try it now.

Answer (score 0):

add `border-width: 5px;` in the css

Comment: Should I add it in every selector?